# Windows 7 VPN Connection over Android 3G network problem

Tags: connection-issues, vpn

What I have:

- Windows 7 Notebook with VPN settings (username password),
- Android 4 phone (ASUS 400) as Wi-Fi/USB modem,
- VPN network;

What I need:

- VPN connection in Windows 7 over 3g network shared by my phone.

But I get 619 error every time.
Someone says that android does not work with VPN connection when it shares internet-connection via modem.